# How to declare, a module.export which exports an array, in a .d.ts file

Tags: typescript, typescript-definitions

I have a node js file that exports an array like

```js
const foobar = [{
  foo: "bar"
}]
module.export = foobar
```

How do I write a .d.ts file for this? I tried

```js
export declare const foobar: Ifoobar[];
interface Ifoobar {
  foo: string
}
```

But that isn't what is being exported...
Declaring it as `export default` also doesn't do the job

Is there any way I can achieve this specific kind of type annotation? Sadly I can't change the nodejs file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, I found the answer myself, in case anybody else has the same problem as me, I fixed it by

```js
export = foobar;
declare const foobar: Ifoobar[];
interface Ifoobar {
  foo: string
}
```